# Probability of random line through a point intersecting a circle

Tags: geometry

- Consider a circle of radius $r$ with center $C$ and let $p$ be a point outside the circle ( that is $\operatorname{dist}\left(p,C\right) > r$ ).
- What is the probability that a random line through $p$ will intersect the circle $?$.

My intuition tells me it will be something like $r/\operatorname{dist}\left(p,C\right)$ but I would like a formal proof.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "random line" is chosen with respect to a uniform measure on the angle it makes relative to some fixed orientation (e.g., the positive horizontal axis), then the probability is proportional to the angle measure subtended by the tangent lines drawn from the point $p$ to the circle.  This angle is a function of the radius $r$ and the distance $d > r$ between the circle's center and the point $p$, and is simply $$\theta = 2 \sin^{-1} \frac{r}{d}.$$  Therefore the desired probability is $$\frac{2}{\pi} \sin^{-1} \frac{r}{d}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
There's not loss of generality if

- I take the point $\ds{\color{red}{p}}$ as the origin of coordinates $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{i.e.}\ \pars{0,0}~}}$ and
- the circle center $\ds{\color{red}{C}}$ on the *positive*-$\ds{\hat{x}}$-*axis*. Namely, the "circumference equation" is given by
  $$
  \pars{x - d}^{2} + y^{2} = r^{2}\,,\qquad d \equiv \on{dist}\pars{p,C} > r
  $$

---

- A "line equation", which is tangent to the circle,  is given by $\ds{y = \alpha x}$  where $\ds{\alpha}$ is determined by
  $$
  \pars{x - d}^{2} + \alpha^{2}\,x^{2} = r^{2} \implies
  \pars{\alpha^{2} + 1}x^{2} - 2dx + d^{2} - r^{2} =0 
  $$
- Since both values $\ds{x_{\pm}}$ of $\ds{x}$ must be equal ( by symmetry considerations ):
  $$
  \pars{-2d}^{2} - 4\pars{\alpha^{2} + 1}\pars{d^{2} - r^{2}} = 0 \implies
  \alpha = \pm\,{r \over \root{d^{2} - r^{2}}} 
  $$
  Both tangent lines to the circle span an angle =
  $\ds{2\arctan\pars{r \over \root{d^{2} - r^{2}}}}$

---

Then, the answer is
\begin{align}
& \mbox{} 
\\ &\
{2\arctan\pars{r/\root{d^{2} - r^{2}}} \over \pi} =
\bbx{{2 \over \pi}\,\arctan\pars{r \over \root{d^{2} - r^{2}}}} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: The probability approaches $1$ as $r$ approaches $d$ (only a vertical line avoids the circle in the limit). I would divide by $\pi$ rather than $2\pi$; you're only sampling a slope angle, not a direction angle.

Comment: @DavidK Fixed. Thanks. You're quite right.

Answer (score 0):

By similarity, the probability for a point at distance $d$ of a circle of radius $r$ is indeed the same as for a point at distance $\dfrac dr$ of a unit circle, as only angles are involved. Hence the solution is indeed of the form

$$\phi\left(\frac rd\right).$$

As shown in the other answers, simple trigonometry gives the fraction of angles such that the line meets the circle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Outline:** If all lines are equally likely, they the given problem is equivalent to asking what proportion of lines that contain *p* also intersect with *C*. Since only one side of the line can intersect with *p*, it is natural to introduce an axillary problem which is identical, but lines are replaced with rays. The axillary problem is very easy to solve if you already have the formula for angular diameter. The solution for the axillary problem can then be used to solve the given problem because for every ray that intersects with *C* there is a ray that points in the exact opposite direction and these two rays are associated with the same line.

**Axillary Problem:** What is the probability *P(i)* that a ray originating from point *p* will intersect with circle *C*, assuming that *p* is not circumscribed by *C*.

1: *P(i)* = (number of rays originating from *p* that intersect with *C*) / (number of rays originating from *p*)
[This comes from the mathematical definition of probability.]

2: *P(i)* = angular diameter of *C* from *p*
[This comes from the definition of angular diameter, although I can not find a source that defines angular diameter in this way.]

3: *P(i)* = 2 * arctan(*d*/2*D*), where *d* = the diameter of *C* and *D* is the distance from *p* to the center of *C*.
[[Source](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=angular%20diameter%20formula) that this is the formula for angular diameter in radians.]

**Given Problem:** What is the probability *P(I)* that a line that passes through point *p* will intersect with circle *C*, assuming that *p* is not circumscribed by *C*.

Assumption 1: For any line that contains *p*, there are exactly 2 rays that originate from *p* and are collinear with that line.
[I am not going to prove this because I don't think anyone here is going to question it. I know that is a bad practice, but I am trying to keep this as concise as possible.]

1: *P(I)* = (number of lines containing *p* that intersect with *C*) / (number of lines containing *p*)
[This comes from the mathematical definition of probability.]

2: *P(I)* = (2 * number of rays originating from *p* that intersect with *C*) / (2 * number of rays originating from *p*)
[This follows from assumption 1.]

3: *P(I)* = (number of rays originating from *p* that intersect with *C*) / (number of rays originating from *p*)
[The 2 in the numerator cancels out with the 2 in the denominator.]

4: *P(I)* = 2 * arctan(*d*/2*D*), where *d* = the diameter of *C* and *D* is the distance from *p* to the center of *C*.
[We proved this with the axillary problem.]